# BigQuery extract does not return dates in ISO format

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to export a BQ table in a json file. The table has a lot of nested fields, arrays etc. with Timestamp columns.

When I run a

```
bq extract --destination_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON data:example.table gs://test/export_json.json
```

I get a json back, but the dates are not in the format I would expect. They are in `"ProcessedTimestamp":"2019-03-06 20:20:52.588 UTC"` but I would expect them to be `"ProcessedTimestamp":"2019-03-06T20:20:52.588Z"`.

If I do

```
SELECT
  TO_JSON_STRING(t, TRUE) AS json_example
FROM
  Table
```

then I can see that the dates are in the ISO format. Should not the same be happening on extract since I have specified the format to be `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON`?

Comment: Does the `bq extract` documentation specify how it formats timestamps? I don't think that it claims to use ISO 8601 date-time formatting, although the `TO_JSON_STRING` documentation does.